# Gluing connections on the projective line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\{U_1,U_2\}$ be the standard open cover of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$.  Thus, $U_1=\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{C}[t_1]$ and $U_2=\mathrm{Spec} \,\mathbb{C}[t_2]$ where $t_2=t_1^{-1}$. We take $0\in U_1$ and $\infty\in U_2$.  Let $\nabla_1$ be a connection on the trivial vector bundle $\mathbb{C}^n$ on $U_1$. Assume $\nabla_1$ is regular everywhere except possibly at $0$. Thus, we can write
$$
\nabla_1=d+A_1dt \quad \quad A_1\in \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C}[t_1,t_1^{-1}]). 
$$
Let $\nabla_2$ be a connection on the trivial bundle on $U_2$ which is regular everywhere except possibly at $\infty$. So we may write 
$$
\nabla_2=d+A_2dt,\quad \quad  A_2\in \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C}[t_2,t_2^{-1}]).
$$

Question: Under what conditions does there exists a pair $(V,\nabla)$ consisting of a  vector bundle together with a connection on $\mathbb{P}^1$ whose restriction to $U_i$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}^n, \nabla_i)$? What is the set of isomorphism classes of such pairs $(V,\nabla)$?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the question. You basically have two connections on Spec C[t_1,t_1^{-1}], and you are asking when they are isomorphic (or, equivalently, when two matrices over Laurent polynomials are gauge-equivalent), correct? If so, I don't see how to give a meaningful answer: you can use irregular Riemann-Hilbert to describe connections (in terms of monodromy and Stokes data), but this is pretty much impossible to express in terms of $A_1$ and $A_2$.